# go through a dataframe in R reading it by columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to read each element (and convert it from character to numerical) from column 2 onwards in my dataframe. I have set up this code, but I cannot understand why it is incorrect. May you help me please? I am new with R.

```
for(i in mydata[,-1])
    for(j in mydata[,i])
        type.convert(mydata[j,i], na.strings='NA',as.is = TRUE, dec = '.')
```

Comment: `df[,-1] <- lapply(df[,-1], as.numeric)`?

Comment: Why are your values converted from numeric to character in the first place? You might have better results solving that problem rather than fixing the issue after the fact.

Comment: Your option is working fine, Mike, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with:

```
for(i in 2:length(mydata)){
    mydata[,i]<-as.numeric(mydata[,i])
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It returns this error though:

Error in as.numeric(mydata[, i]) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: @Maya You can type `i` in the console to see which column is causing trouble. Apparently, it's list class, not character.